# printf statement with background and foreground colours

Tags: bash, color-management

I know that a background colour code is `\033[41m`, whereas a foreground colour code is `\033[32m`.  I am interested in making a code for changing the background and foreground in a console terminal printf statement.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Read `man console_codes tput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SGR (Select Graphic Rendition) parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR_(Select_Graphic_Rendition)_parameters) may be concatenated, separated by `;`

Ex.

```
printf '\033[41;32m%s\033[0m\n' foobar
```

will print `foobar` with background red (41) and foreground green (32).

Answer (score 0):

```
printf '\033[32;44m'
#        ESC[ Foreground═3 + $Nr.Color Register ; Background═4 + $Nr.Color Register hold vale of color
```

Comment: The asker was looking for an explanation, not a code snippet

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1339754)

Answer (score 0):

These codes can be used to change individual register values. So you can change the color completely in the printout ready.:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]
then : # palet
echo -en "\033[?47h" # Swap_buffer
          #black     #red       #green     #Orange    #blue      #magenta   #cyan     #(S) white
echo -ne "\e]P0000000\e]P17F0000\e]P2008000\e]P3FF4600\e]P42020AF\e]P5BF00BF\e]P600CDCD\e]P7A0A0A0"
          #L black   #L red     #L green   #L yellow  #L blue    #L Cream   #S Blue    #L white
echo -ne "\e]P8404040\e]P9C41414\e]PA3CFF00\e]PBE2E200\e]PC4141FF\e]PDFFC8C8\e]PE9696FF\e]PFFFFFFF"
# get rid of artifacts
# clear
echo -en "\033[?47l" # Main_buffer
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The general format for setting text color using ANSI escape codes is:

\033[<style>;<foreground>;<background>m

- \033 escape character in octal representation, which starts the ANSI escape sequence.
- [ is the control sequence introducer.
- <style>, <foreground>, and  are placeholders for numeric codes that represent text styles (like bold or underline),
  foreground (text) colors, and background colors, respectively.
- m indicates that the sequence is a color/graphics mode setting.

This is a sample bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define color and reset
RED_TEXT="\033[0;31m"
GREEN_BG="\033[42m"
RESET="\033[0m"

# Use variables
echo -e "${RED_TEXT}${GREEN_BG}Hello, World!${RESET}"
```

Here's a quick reference for some common foreground and background colors:

Foreground Colors:

```
Black: 30
Red: 31
Green: 32
Yellow: 33
Blue: 34
Magenta: 35
Cyan: 36
White: 37
```

Background Colors:

```
Black: 40
Red: 41
Green: 42
Yellow: 43
Blue: 44
Magenta: 45
Cyan: 46
White: 47
```